# I have kept Shani Dev Idol at home, visiting people advise to not keep it. What should i do?

Tags: shani

I suffered from Sade Sati from 2012 to 2019. And this period's extreme difficulties brought me closer to Shani Dev. My sade sati got over in 2019 and ever since then I have been growing tremendously in all areas of my life. (personal/Professional)

I strongly believe that Shani Dev has bestowed blessings on me post sade sati period.

So 1 year back I bought Shani Dev Murti and kept in my place of worship. I daily light agarbattis and pray to him. I have also offered Oil to him. Also read shani stories. (Shani-Mahatmya)

People who visit me say that it's not good to keep his idol. We should not worship him from front, not look at him etc.

But exactly the opposite has happened, Ever since I brought his idol home only positive things have happened in my life.

Comment: Yes it is not advisable to keep Shanidev in home. In my region too people have the same belief. It's a risky thing because Shani is basically a Krura Graha.

Comment: As per Tantras, Shani's Ishta Dev is Goddess Kali. So by worshipping Kali one can pacify Shani. Similarly by worshipping Hanuman too one can pacify Shani. So if your goal is to remedy a malefic Shani then that can be achieved by worshipping either Goddess Kali or Hanuman. No need to take the risk of keeping a Shani idol in home IMO.

Comment: What about books on Shani dev?

Comment: How can you tell if an idol has brought you blessings? It could be pure luck.